"MediaRendererUpdated" event bug
I understand it is an "unlikely" scenario, but it may be helpful: changing video settings during an active screen-sharing session causes some "unexpected" behavior. In my case, changing video settings caused screen share to "break" and show a local preview, skipping some conditional handler I had for the "MediaRendererUpdate" with the video type.
I was checking if there is a way to change the quality of the screen share feed. I wasn't sure it would work, but at least I wasn't expecting screen sharing to break (not to mention, the fact that this change does not trigger the conditional block I had for the event with the type of video). Originally, I thought It might be just a problem on my part, but when I checked the vox implant conference solution (videoconf.voximplant.com) I experienced the same problem. I tried to find the reason, and one thing I discovered is that the "MediaRendererUpdated" hardware event emitted has a different value of the "type" property: in some cases, it is 'video', and in other cases, it is 'Video' (I assume the problem is related to the MediaRendererKind enum key/value upper/lower-case difference).

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
